# Is it better to hire a system administrator or do it yourself?

Tags: linux

I previously asked a question on here asking the risks in hiring a sys admin to secure my server. I got some great answers, I appreciate them. What I want to know is, to eliminate the risks Should I learn how to secure my Linux server myself? ( if yes a point in the right guide for beginners is appreciated).

Comment: I don't see why I am being voted down. All am asking is links towards the right start. Learning to secure a linux server for the first time is hard and I think my question is a good one.

Comment: I'm not one of the people who downvoted you, so I'm only guessing.  That said, I suspect one issue is that requests for product or learning material recommendations are considered off topic because they attract poor-quality answers.  Another is that, well.  You're not going to replace an IT security consultant or system administrator overnight by reading a FAQ.  System administration is a complex field that requires constant learning.

Comment: Thank you for your comment it actually helps. So basically the choice I have as a new comer is to hire a sys admin?

Comment: My personal feeling is that hiring someone competent and experienced is less risky than doing it yourself if you're a complete newbie.  You always have a choice, of course.

Comment: Thank you Katherine Villyard. I think I'll hire someone.

Answer (score 1):

Hire SA, it is best to have someone experienced. Not to say anyone is not capable of learning but there is just a lot a book cannot teach and   if you are running a business you probably would not have time to invest into higher education such as network security and administration. One slip and you could expose or lose all your data.